# passing list item name as a list type to function

Tags: python, list, casting

This is a short snippet from my code while solving [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42031812/process-monitoring-tool-in-python") problem. I want to push items in the list into stack, but same item name should be used as a list name when passing to `run` function. My intent is something close to depth first search and base case to stop recursion is to be included soon in my code.
Is there any way to `cast` item popped to be taken as a list name argument.

```
#Below is dependency list
p1-['p2','p3']
p2=['p3','p4']
p3=['p4']
p4=[]
p5=[]

def run(pro=[])
    if pro: #process has a dependency, push its items dependency into stack
        for dependency in pro:
            stack.push(dependency)
        run(stack.peek) #I need to pass top item of stack as a list
```

Comment: Don't use separate variables, use a dictionary that maps names to lists. Then you can look up the dependency in the dictionary.

Comment: Be careful using mutable default arguments! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument

Comment: @Barmar Even if I take a dict and push every list item for a key, then also how do I tell python to take the stack.peek element as a key of dict. Fairly new to python, could you please elaborate on how this would be achieved. Thanks

Comment: If `dependencies` is the dict, `stack.push(dependencies[dependency])`

Comment: @Barmar I understand pushing, but what is the way to pass top most item on stack as a list to `run`. I hope my understanding that we are pushing items on the list into stack and not whole lists.

Comment: You can concatenate the whole dependency list onto the stack with `stack += dependencies[dependency]`. This will push all the items onto the stack.

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to understand this approach. :(

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example recursive, dictionary-based approach:

```
dependencies = { \
    'p1': ['p2', 'p3'], \
    'p2': ['p3', 'p4'], \
    'p3': ['p4'], \
    'p4': [], \
    'p5': [] \
    }

def run_order(process, order=None):

    if order is None:
        order = []

    precursors = dependencies[process]

    if precursors:
        for precursor in precursors:
            run_order(precursor, order)

        if process not in order:
            order.append(process)  # should really be insert after right-most precursor

    elif process not in order:
            order.insert(0, process)  # no dependencies, start ASAP

    return order

print(run_order('p1'))
```

**PRINTS**

```
['p4', 'p3', 'p2', 'p1']
```

Does this order the processes correctly for your purposes?  (You will need to test various scenarios.)  Another approach is to allow `run_order()` to take a list of processes:

```
def run_order(processes, order=None):

    if order is None:
        order = []

    for process in processes:
        precursors = dependencies[process]

        if precursors:
            run_order(dependencies[process], order)

            if process not in order:
                order.append(process) # should really be insert after right-most precursor

        elif process not in order:
            order.insert(0, process)  # no dependencies, start ASAP

    return order

print(run_order(['p1']))
print(run_order(list(dependencies.keys())))
```

**PRINTS**

```
['p4', 'p3', 'p2', 'p1']
['p5', 'p4', 'p3', 'p2', 'p1']
```

Again, test various scenarios to decide if it works for your purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the example, it seems to work fine for me. I was thinking how to handle a restart case aswell. eg. Till now we are considering starting processes. To restart, with `P5->P1` given, then after restarting P1, we also need to start P5 because it was dependent on P1 and since P1 is to be restarted P5 should also be restarted.